# Duplicate content on the same domain but different description title and keywords?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, meta-tags

I have a question concerning a specific case of duplicate content when it is on the same domain.

Let us assume that I have a Flash games website, and I want to rank the website for puzzle games which also may be called thinking games and brain games, so I have 3 categories: puzzle, thinking and brain games, which all have the same games (content) but they should have different titles, descriptions, and meta keywords.

What is the best way to deal with this situation from both the user and search engine point of view?

Comment: Google might call it [doorway page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721311?hl=en) spam: "Substantially similar pages that are closer to search results than a clearly defined, browseable hierarchy"

Comment: You can use a canonical tag to point to one copy of the page for search indexing. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en Otherwise, you are taking a risk as to which one will be chosen. Not all will appear in the SERPs. As for users, that is up to you. Without knowing your site, there is no way for us to comment. It sounds like the pages can be combined if there is so little difference.

Comment: so what would be the best way to target keywords that have the same meaning while not having two different pages that rank for different keywords ? i can of course make a mix of the synonyms in the same page but that won't be very efficient ? my question  is how can  i have two pages that have same content yet have different title and description ( so i can rank for both of them, but tile and description would have the same meaning but using different synonyms ) while actually both of them rank the same for keywords in the title and the description in both of the two pages?